# Обратная связь телеграм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как сделать в боте телеграм обратную связь? У меня есть бот в котором юзер скидывает фото боту, бот пересылает это фото мне, под фото есть inline markup с надписями "Да" и "Нет", и вот как так сделать что бы когда я нажимал на кнопку "Да" под фото, бот писал "Привет", а если нажимаю "Нет" то бот пишет юзеру "Пока" именно тому юзеру, который отправил это фото.
Библиотека telebot

```
        def process_number(message):
            try:

                if message.content_type != 'photo':
                    raise ValueError
                process_chat_id(message, message.photo[-1].file_id)

            except ValueError:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ошибка")
            except OverflowError:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка')

        def process_chat_id(message, file_id):
            try:
                chat_id = message.chat.id

                
                user_link = f"<a href='tg://user?id={chat_id}'>Пользователь</a>"
                bot.send_photo(519299127, file_id, caption=f'{user_link}, отправил фото', parse_mode='HTML')

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Фото было успешно отправлено!")
               # bot.register_next_step_handler(message, hello)
            except ValueError:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ошибка")
            except Exception as e:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " Ошибка: {}".format(e))

        if message.text=="Фото":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Хорошо, присылай свое фото сюда")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_number)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если обходиться без использования баз данных то можно вот так

Код создания кнопки во время получения фото от пользователя:

```
sender_id = message.chat.id    
reply_kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
             types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="✅Да", callback_data=f"1 {sender_id}" ),
             types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="❌Нет", callback_data=f"0 {sender_id}" )
             )
```

Обработка колбека и отправка сообщения:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
data_list = list(map(int,call.data.split()))
if call.message.chat.id in admins_list:
 sender_id = data_list[1]
 if data_list[0]==0:
  bot.send_message(sender_id ,"Пока") 
 else:
  bot.send_message(sender_id ,"Привет")
```

**Объяснение работы:**

В call.data можно передавать строку с параметрами разделенные, например
пробелом. В данном случаем передаем два параметра первый это id кнопки 0-нет 1-да, вторым передали  id юзера который прислал фото.
Далее в callback_query_handler парсим строку и заполняем data_list параметрами кнопки которая была нажата. Соответственно data_list[0] это id кнопки которая была нажата, datalist[1] - id юзера который прислал фото.
Далее в соответствии с нажатой кнопкой отправляем сообщение.

Так как callback можно подделать добавил проверку на наличие пользователя нажавшего кнопку в списке администраторов. А так же обратите внимание на описанное в документации ограничение количества данных передаваемых в callback.data.

Comment: Благодарю вас!!